# Javascript Promise/Then Example

Tags: javascript

I wanted to create an example for my understanding of `Promise().then()`.
I've created an operation that takes time and have operations that must be completed synchronously.
The code is below:

```
// Example: long operation that takes time to execute
var longOperation = function(id) {

    var time = 1000 * Math.random();

    console.log('[' + id + '] Operation started for: ' + time + 'ms');

    setTimeout(function(err) {
        console.log('[' + id + '] Completed operation:   ' + time + 'ms');
        var count = id * 10;
    }, 1000 * Math.random());

};

// Create new promise for longOperation
var longOpPromise = function(id) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        longOperation(id);
        resolve(null);
    });

};

// Create sequencing
var runLongOperation = function(callback) {

    var count1;

    longOpPromise(1).then(function(count) {

        count1 = count;
        console.log('Count 1: ' + count1);

        longOpPromise(2).then(function(count2) {
            console.log('Count 2: ' + count2);
            callback(null, count1, count2);
        });

    });

};

// Run
runLongOperation(function(err, count1, count2) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    console.log('Count 1 ' + count1 + ' | Count 2: ' + count2);
});
```

The result of running:

```
    **** Output ****
    [1] Operation started for: 626.77225866355ms
    [1] Completed operation:   626.77225866355ms
```

The methods in `then()` are not executed, nor is the callback. Maybe count is not being resolved.

If I change it to `resolve(null)`, these execute but not in sequence:

```
    **** Output ****
    [1] Operation started for: 435.5367429088801ms
    Count 1: null // This should come after [1] is completed
    [2] Operation started for: 256.17250707000494ms
    Count 2: null // This should come after [2] is completed
    Count 1 null | Count 2: null // This should come after [2] is completed
    [2] Completed operation:   256.17250707000494ms
    [1] Completed operation:   435.5367429088801ms
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `resolve` *when the asynchronous operation is **complete***.

With this code:

> ```
> longOperation(id);
> resolve(null);
> ```

You are **starting** the asynchronous operation and then **immediately** resolving the promise.

---

If you want to pass the value of `count` to your `then` function, then you need to pass it when you call `resolve()`. At the moment you are passing `null`.

---

This version of your code modifies it to pass `resolve` as a callback and only call it at the right time.

```js
// Example: long operation that takes time to execute
var longOperation = function(id, resolve) {
  var time = 1000 * Math.random();
  console.log('[' + id + '] Operation started for: ' + time + 'ms');

  setTimeout(function(err) {
    console.log('[' + id + '] Completed operation:   ' + time + 'ms');
    var count = id * 10;
    resolve(count);
  }, 1000 * Math.random());
};

// Create new promise for longOperation
var longOpPromise = function(id) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    longOperation(id, resolve);
  });
};

// Create sequencing
var runLongOperation = function(callback) {
  var count1;
  longOpPromise(1).then(function(count) {
    count1 = count;
    console.log('Count 1: ' + count1);

    longOpPromise(2).then(function(count2) {
      console.log('Count 2: ' + count2);
      callback(null, count1, count2);
    });
  });
};

// Run
runLongOperation(function(err, count1, count2) {
  if (err) console.error(err);
  console.log('Count 1 ' + count1 + ' | Count 2: ' + count2);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue here is that your async action (`setTimeout`) is not involved with your promise chain.

The `resolve(null)` after `longOperation(id)` will immediately return null and not wait for the `longOperation` function to finish its timeout interval.

Something like this will work:

```
// Example: long operation that takes time to execute
var longOperation = function(id) {

    var time = 1000 * Math.random();

    console.log('[' + id + '] Operation started for: ' + time + 'ms');

    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function(err) {
            console.log('[' + id + '] Completed operation:   ' + time + 'ms');
            var count = id * 10;
            resolve(count);
        }, time);
    });

};

// Create new promise for longOperation
var longOpPromise = function(id) {
    return longOperation(id);
};
```

I moved the `new Promise` inside of the `longOperation` and resolve only when the `setTimeout` callback is handled.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is these two lines:

```
longOperation(id);
resolve(null);
```

Because `longOperation` is an asynchronous function, `resolve(null)` will run BEFORE `longOperation` has finished running.

I would combine the two first functions to make sure that the promise does not resolve UNTIL the callback in the `setTimeout` has run:

```
var longOpPromise = function(id) {

    var time = 1000 * Math.random();

    console.log('[' + id + '] Operation started for: ' + time + 'ms');

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function(err) {
            console.log('[' + id + '] Completed operation:   ' + time + 'ms');
            var count = id * 10;
            resolve() // Now the promise won't resolve until here.
        }, 1000 * Math.random());
    })


};
```

I would also avoid mixing callbacks and promises like you are doing - except for inbuilt functions like `setTimeout`, if you are using promises then you should be able to avoid using callbacks.